# Is this code safe (why it's not crashing)?

Tags: c++, c

I saw a solution for list merge sort:

```
struct Node* SortedMerge(struct Node* a, struct Node* b)
{
  struct Node* result = NULL;

  /* Base cases */
  if (a == NULL)
     return(b);
  else if (b==NULL)
     return(a);

  /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
  if (a->data <= b->data)
  {
     result = a;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b);
  }
  else
  {
     result = b;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next);
  }
  return(result);
}
```

And it seems that it is not safe because `struct Node* result` is allocate on the stack, and need to be free after returning from the function call.

I checked and it works (without crash).

So is the code safe ? and why ?

Comment: `result` is a pointer. The return value of the function is not a pointer to `result`. Instead, it is a pointer to the object which `result` is also pointing to.

Comment: Would you have the same concern about `int i;`?

Comment: You are checking if both a and b aren't null, before dereferencing them, so I don't see how it isn't code safe?  The result* is allocated on the stack (not the heap) so you do not need to worry about it.  you are only updating where it is pointing to, unless of course you are saying you want to delete a or b when you leave the function which isn't what this function reads it does.

Comment: provide some [MCVE]

Comment: Be sure to check the return of SortedMerge calls for null.  If both a and b are both null, b (null) gets returned.

Comment: Concerning the question in the title, although I don't know what "safe" is intended to mean, it almost certainly means something more than "it didn't crash when I ran it".

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are not allocating it dynamically it is not your responsibility to deallocate it. I don't see why this would fail simply because it is on `stack`.

This would not lead to error.

It would be bad if you allocate result on every call to the function and then dont free it as this would lead to memory leak.

Also it would be error if you try to return an address of a local variable from the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that the recursion will blow the stack, then you're right; in most cases maximum stack size is limited (e.g. on Windows x64 it is 1MB by default).

So you can recurse a maximum of around 32767 times before you blow the stack (assuming at least return address also needs to be stored on the stack).

That's why you should avoid recursion on user-provided data and prefer iteration instead.

Answer (score 0):

well not quite, only the variable result is allocated in stack but actual memory is still in heap, more over nothing is allocated in-stack

```
 struct Node* result = NULL;
```

these statements below are mere pointers pointing to memory pointed to by pointer a or b or memory returned by SortedMerge( );

```
result = a;
result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b);
result = b;
result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next);
```

and these are possibly allocated in heap or by a local allocated memory by a called function, in which case memory still exists as long as the calling function scope exists.

returning address of a local variable is an error however passing address of local variable is considered perfectly fine.